# Query Shows too much instead of the right brewer PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a query to show all beers and brewers in a table, but when using this query, the results show the beer & all the brewers, so for example I get as result the beers with a list of all the brewers.
I think i did something wrong with the inner join, but i don't know what.

```
SELECT * FROM bieren INNER JOIN brouwers ON bieren.naam LIKE "du%" AND brouwers.brnaam LIKE "a%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add the foreign key to the join as well. A beer probably has a brewerid or something. Also, although your query 'works', it is more common to have the filter conditions in the `WHERE` clause of the query. Adding a little white space too, your query could then look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  bieren 
INNER JOIN brouwers 
  ON bieren.brouwerid = brouwers.brouwerid
WHERE
  bieren.naam LIKE "du%" AND 
  brouwers.brnaam LIKE "a%"
```

Comment: I found that the inner join has to be with bieren.brouwernr = brouwers.brouwernr but if i use the query now, i get an empty table

Comment: That means there are not brouwers that start with `a` which brew a beer that starts with `du`. Or maybe the brouwernrs are not filled in correctly. Note that the comparison *can* be case sensitive, depending on the table collation, but I'd check the data first. Start with removing the where clause, if that doesn't give you data, then the brouwernrs are not ok. If the 'bare' join gives you data, start adding the other conditions.

Comment: Ah got it, i made a typo cause i needed to select all brewere with an "a" in there name so it was %a%, So your answer helped me a lot, thanks. Also you gave me a good way to kind of debug it to see what's wrong, thanks a lot!.